# Custom Validation won't display

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="PresZipValidator" ControlToValidate="txtZip"  
                runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required Field" EnableClientScript="false" 
                ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

My validation will not display on my web form..any suggestions? I have a button event to see if the page is valid and nothing shows up.

Comment: What's in the handler for this validator?

Comment: protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { if (txtZip.Text != "")
            {
                PresZipValidator.IsValid = true;
            }
            else { 
                PresZipValidator.IsValid = false; 
            }

Comment: I think you want to set `Text="Required Field"`, you only use `ErrorMessage` if you're using a `ValidationSummary`. Also, you could use an asp:RequiredFieldValidator for what you want, and then you don't need the server validation function.

Answer (score 0):

First off - if your validation is that the field is required, consider using a RequiredFieldValidator control instead.

The Text property is what is displayed directly from the validator control. You can use a ValidationSummary control to display the ErrorMessage property from all failing validators.

For the CustomValidator control, you should consider implementing a client-side javascript validation as well (if possible) and point to it using the ClientValidationFunction property.